# Best practice for get request with some query and sortable fields in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, http, asp.net-web-api

I have this action in `CommodityTypeController`:

```
[HttpGet("")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string name, int page = 1, int count = 10)
{
    var result = await commodityTypeService.Get(name: name, page, count);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

which returns a list of `CommodityTypeDto`.

This is my `CommodityTypeService`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CommodityTypeDto>> Get(string name,int page, int count)
{
    var entities = await commodityTypeRepository.Get(x => name.HasValue() ? x.Name.Contains(name) : true, page, count);
    var dtos = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CommodityTypeDto>>(entities);
    return dtos;
}
```

And this is my `CommodityTypeDto`:

```
public class CommodityTypeDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal AccountNumberId { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, this is my `CommodityTypeRepository` :

```
public async virtual Task<IEnumerable<CommodityType>> Get(Expression<Func<CommodityType, bool>> expression, int page, int count)
{
    var result = await set.Where(expression)
                          .Skip((page-1) * count)
                          .Take(count)
                          .ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

What is  best practice for create a get api? If I want to search with more parameters and sort per some field in my API, is this a good method?

Is there any library for sorting and querying from an API to an EF context?

Comment: Is it a requirement to do filtering, sorting, searching server side? Why not delegate that responsibility to the client?

Comment: @nbokmans yes, this is good thing if move this actions to client, but i want find out how can perform this actions in server side.

Answer (score 0):

On the back end You should apply filtering to minimize the traffic from server to the client. 
On the front end You should apply sorting and filtering over returned results.
Imagine the situation when you want to sort a really big amount of data on the back end. For every change of the sorting criteria the same amount of data will be transferred.